# Get value of an input in an ASHX from a master page in Angular/asp project

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

I searched a lot on the internet but nothing answered to my problem.

I need to get/set in my api.ashx a value of an input text in my master page.

**Main.Master.cs**

```
<input type="hidden" id="token" name="token" runat="server" />
```

**api.ashx**

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
      //here i need to get or set the "token" input in master page 
}
```

Comment: Hmm... what exactly are you trying? The call to ashx and a page are two different requests. You might perhaps Redirect your call inside ProcessRequest via ```context.Response.Redirect(newUrl);
``` and pass an URL Parameter...

Comment: I need to store a token in the input text in my master page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using jQuery and aspnet Controls. It takes the value From TextBox1 and sends it to the handler. Then the handler send another value back and it is put inside TextBox1. You may need to adjust it to your specific scenario.

**The handler code**

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

    //check if the querystring with the token exists
    if (context.Request.QueryString["token"] != null)
    {
        //get the old token from the querystring (and do stuff with it)
        string oldToken = context.Request.QueryString["token"];

        //check if oldToken contains a value
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(oldToken))
        {
            return;
        }

        //generate a new token
        string newToken = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        //send it to the browser
        context.Response.Write(newToken);
    }
}
```

**The aspx**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="250"></asp:TextBox>
<br /><br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Get Set Token" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClientClick="getSetData(); return;" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function getSetData() {
        var control = "#<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>";
        var oldToken = $(control).val();
        $.get("/TokenHandler.ashx?token=" + oldToken, function (newToken) {
            $(control).val(newToken);
        });
    }
</script>
```